# Is it possible to pipe qemu-img into SSH target?

Tags: ssh, kvm-virtualization, qemu, pipe

I tried the following command, but only an empty file is created on the target and the command stays open

```
qemu-img convert -f raw -O vmdk /dev/sda1 - | ssh foo@bar "cat > /home/foo/foobar.vmdk"
```

Note: `sshfs` is not available.

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible. See comments in the answer comments. Gerald Schneider is a right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to write the `qemu-img` output to a pipe due to the fact that the output files need to be seekable

Ref: https://www.mail-archive.com/qemu-discuss@nongnu.org/msg05176.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that using `qemu-img` alone (as documented in https://serverfault.com/a/1113484/217241 ), but you can instead use the `qemu-nbd` (network block device) utility which accompanies `qemu-img` together with the `nbdcopy` command from libguestfs.  On Debian and derived distros, `nbdcopy` can be found in the `libnbd-bin` package.

```
nbdcopy -- [ qemu-nbd -f qcow2 myVM.qcow2 ] - | ssh user@otherhost cat '>' raw-image-elsewhere
```

The opposite would be:

```
ssh user@otherhost cat raw-image-elsewhere | nbdcopy -- - [ qemu-nbd -f qcow2 local.qcow2 ]
```

Actually it **is** possible to use a combination of `nbdkit` and `qemu-img`, but the nbdkit author recommends using `nbdcopy` with `qemu-nbd` instead: https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/streaming-nbd-server/

n.b. As an aside, if you're constrained by network bandwidth, then you might also want to use the `-C` flag to ssh to compress the data in transit, or otherwise pipe through `zstd` or similar.